# iOS can't alloc new object in switch case

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I have a switch case like this:

```
  switch ([weatherCode intValue]) {
       case 1:
           ...
           break;
       case 2:
           ....
           break;
  }
```

But i want to alloc an object in that case, like `NSString *string = @"hello";`

but it keep gives me an error `expect expression` which i don't understand what's going on at all. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: All statements in all cases of a switch statement are in the same scope, so when you declare a variable with a name in one case, and then you declare a variable with a same name under a different case, you're effectively making the declaration twice.  The error isn't in the allocation or the definition, it's in the declaration.  You either use curly braces to create a new scope in each case, or you just declare your variable once, before the `switch`, and defer assigning until the `case`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had same problem before, simply add a `{}` in your case, all your problem will be solved.

Such as:

```
switch ([weatherCode intValue]) {
   case 1:
   {
      ...
   }
       break;
   case 2:
   {
      ...
   }          
   break;
}
```

Comment: I am so done with the objective C/Xcode BS.

Comment: great solution :D

Answer (score 7):

You need braces if you want initialise variable:

```
switch ([weatherCode intValue]) {
       case 1:{
           NSString *string = @"hello";
       }
       break;
       case 2: {
           ....
       }
       break;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

In (Objective-)C(++) the *statements* `while(...) { ... }`, `for(...) { ... }`, `switch(...) { ...}` etc. contain a single *block statement* (`if (...) { ... } else { ... }` contains two). The scope of *declarations* within a block is just that block, and it is an error to declare the same variable twice within a block.

The block of a `switch` contains a number of `case ...:` *labels* - labels do not delimit blocks, they are just points within a block that control flow can jump to. This makes `switch` statements in C different than in some other languages where each branch is independent (as the two blocks in an `if/else` are independent in C). A C `switch` is just a "computed goto" into a single block. This is why the `break;` statement exists, without it control flow just continues from one "branch" to the next.

Another consequence of this is that different branches cannot declare the same variable names, unlike for `if/else` statements.

Finally only *statements* and not *declarations* can be labelled, and as a `case ...:` is a form of label there cannot be a declaration immediately following one - so you cannot start a "branch" with a declaration.

If the variables you wish to declare within a branch are for use only in that branch (as they would be if declared in either of the blocks of an `if/else`) then you can solve all the problems by enclosing the branch in braces, `{ ... }`, to make it into a block statement - blocks can be labelled and can contain local declarations. E.g. something along the lines of:

```
switch (expr)
{
   case 1:
      {
         NSString *var;
         // use var
         break;
      }

   case 2:
      {
         NSNumber *var;
         // use var
         break;
      }

   ...
}
// no var here
```

If you are assigning to variables which you need to use after the `switch` then you must declare them before the `switch`, as the body of a `switch` is a block and hence a local declaration scope. E.g. something along the lines of:

```
NSString *var = nil;
switch (expr)
{
   case 1:
      ...
      var = ...;
      break;

   case 2:
      ...
      var = ...;
      break;

   ...
}
// use var here
```

HTH

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer. (voted)

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it like this:

```
switch ([weatherCode intValue]) {
   case 1: {
       ...
   }
   break;
   case 2: {
       ....
   }
   break;
   ...
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use some braces :

```
switch ([weatherCode intValue]) {
       case 1:{
           NSString *string = @"hello";
       }
           break;
       case 2:{
           NSString *string = @"hello";
       }
           break;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the switch, cases acts like block so you may need to set the { }. You don't need to explicitly alloc the NSString if using ARC.

```
switch ([weatherCode intValue]) {
   case 1:
   {
      //your code for case 1
   }
       break;
   case 2:
   {
      //your code for case 2
   }          
   break;
}
```